# Pushing base64 encoded image to Google Contacts with Python

Tags: python, google-api, base64, google-contacts-api

I have a base64 encoded jpeg image which I want to push as a Google Contact photo using the API which is explained here: [Updating a photo for a contact](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#addingupdating_a_photo_for_a_contact).

Looking at the documentation for the ChangePhoto method gives the following:

```
Type:        instancemethod
String form: <bound method ContactsClient.change_photo of <gdata.contacts.client.ContactsClient object at 0x104756090>>
File:        /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gdata/contacts/client.py
Definition:  a.ChangePhoto(self, media, contact_entry_or_url, content_type=None, content_length=None, auth_token=None, **kwargs)
Docstring:
Change the photo for the contact by uploading a new photo.

Performs a PUT against the photo edit URL to send the binary data for the
photo.

Args:
  media: filename, file-like-object, or a gdata.data.MediaSource object to send.
  contact_entry_or_url: ContactEntry or str If it is a ContactEntry, this
                        method will search for an edit photo link URL and
                        perform a PUT to the URL.
  content_type: str (optional) the mime type for the photo data. This is
                necessary if media is a file or file name, but if media
                is a MediaSource object then the media object can contain
                the mime type. If media_type is set, it will override the
                mime type in the media object.
  content_length: int or str (optional) Specifying the content length is
                  only required if media is a file-like object. If media
                  is a filename, the length is determined using
                  os.path.getsize. If media is a MediaSource object, it is
                  assumed that it already contains the content length.
```

My problem here is, that I do not have a file-like-object. I guess that my only option then is to create a gdata.data.MediaSource object. The problem with this is that I can't find any good documentation on how to construct such an object correct.

How do I construct such a gdata.data.MediaSource object from my base64-encoded image. How do I specify the content_type and the content_length correctly?

Comment: [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) is a file-like object.

Comment: Unfortunately, MediaSource objects simply store information on file-type objects, so that won't help you.

Comment: How is your base64-encoded image stored in your program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python offers you in-memory file-like objects. On Python 2, use [`cStringIO.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html#module-cStringIO) (with a fallback to `StringIO.StringIO` in the rare cases the C-optimised version is missing):

```
try:
    from cStringIO import StringIO
except ImportError:
    from StringIO import StringIO

image_data = your_image_data.decode('base64')
image_file = StringIO(image_data)

a.ChangePhoto(
    image_file, contact_url, content_type='image/jpg',
    content_length=len(image_data))
```

I do assume that your Base64-encoded image data (stored in `your_image_data` is straight-up encoded, not a [data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

Comment: I get the the following error back: Server responded with: 415, Content-Type image/jpeg is not a valid input type.

I tried changing it to image/png and image/*, but neither worked. The data in my image_data looks like the byte-code of a PNG-image (it has a "PNG" in the beginning).

Comment: @utdiscant: Interesting; I thought you had a JPEG (your question says so). You can try `image/jpg` (the more common mime type, my mistake).

Comment: @utdiscant: but JPEG starts the bytes FF F9 (and will have the ascii characters JFIF or EXIF in there somewhere), PNG with 89 then PNG then 0D 0A 1A 0A.

Comment: @utdiscant: otherwise, hard to say what is going on without actual data.

Comment: Now I have an image with "JFIF" in the beginning. Google still returns a "Server responded with: 415, Content-Type image/jpg is not a valid input type.". It seems like it just plain rejects any image/* content_type.

Comment: @utdiscant: that, or fields are mixed up; e.g. Google received `image/jpg` where it expected something entirely different.

Comment: @utdiscant: I checked the source code some more and the `content_type` and `content_length` are passed to the `MediaSource` object created from the file object, directly. Those are then passed on to the PUT request. I cannot see why Google would complain about the mimetype here. But again, sample data would help here.

Comment: Here is an example of such an object: http://pastebin.com/dMiVqAtR as a string which can be decoded with base64.b64decode

Comment: @utdiscant: that's definitely PNG. Google won't accept that image as valid? (It's the default Google avatar for when you don't have an avatar yet).